# React Native Input is off screen

Tags: react-native, input, scrollview

I'm attempting to implement an Input field at the bottom of my project's screen, however something in my code is prohibiting this from happening.

my code is as follows:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginTop:-30,}}>
    //This is where my 'header' is
    <ScrollView 
      ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{        
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
    }}
    style={{ marginBottom: 150}}>
//Objects in my ScrollView will be here
    </ScrollView>
<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
      <Input
      containerStyle={{
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 162, 255, 1)'
                    }}
  placeholder='Enter Text Here'
  leftIcon={
    <Icon
      name='add'
      type='material'
      size={24}
      color='white'
    />
  }

/>
</View>
</View>
```

so a little explanation: my ScrollView has a `marginBottom` of 150 because for some reason without that my screen will not show the entire `ScrollView`; some parts of it are cut off the screen and if I scroll all the way down some objects are cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the absolute position of `Input` like this:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginTop:-30,}}>
    //This is where my 'header' is
    <ScrollView 
      ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
      onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{        
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
      }}
      style={{ marginBottom: 150}}>
      //Objects in my ScrollView will be here
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 30 }}>
      <Input
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 162, 255, 1)'
        }}
        placeholder='Enter Text Here'
        leftIcon={
          <Icon
            name='add'
            type='material'
            size={24}
            color='white'
          />
          }
      />
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: unfortunately the problem persists :(

Comment: it works on my [end](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/position-absolute-test). i have no idea what `<Input />` component you used, so i've used `<TextInput />` instead.

Comment: That actually solved my issue! I was using a UI Library, but decided to just use the regular TextInput and it's working now! Thank you